# Cannot set 1G speed on 10G nic using ethtool

Tags: performance, nic, ethtool

I have a linux server with 10G fibre nics:

```
xyz@xyz48:~$ sudo ethtool p1p1
Settings for p1p1:
    Supported ports: [ FIBRE ]
    Supported link modes:   10000baseT/Full 
    Supported pause frame use: No
    Supports auto-negotiation: No
    Advertised link modes:  10000baseT/Full 
    Advertised pause frame use: No
    Advertised auto-negotiation: No
    Speed: 10000Mb/s
    Duplex: Full
    Port: Direct Attach Copper
    PHYAD: 0
    Transceiver: external
    Auto-negotiation: off
    Supports Wake-on: d
    Wake-on: d
    Current message level: 0x00000007 (7)
                   drv probe link
    Link detected: no
```

For an experiment, I want to set the maximu speed here to 1 Gb.

On searching online I found that this command should do the job:

```
sudo ethtool -s p1p1 advertise 0x020 speed 1000
```

But when I run it I get the following error:

```
Cannot set new settings: Invalid argument
  not setting advertise
  not setting speed
```

Anything I am missing? Or is it that form my case I will need to change the driver?

Server details:
Intel Xeon based Server

NIC: Intel Corporation 82599ES 10-Gigabit SFI/SFP+ Network Connection

Using a 10G SFP+ cable (Arista cab-sfp-sfp-1m)

OS Ubuntu Server 13.10

Comment: Your NIC doesn't appear to support this.

Comment: What NIC is this?  It says 'FIBRE', but then lists 10000BaseT...

Comment: Posted some of the details about the server that I have

Comment: @MichaelHampton I think in this case  possibly the driver may be the problem, as the manufacturer claims that  1 Gb/s or 100 Mb/s speeds are also supported by [this NIC](http://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/ethernet-controllers/82599-10-gbe-controller-datasheet.html). But more likely the SFP+ module dictates the physical layer which results in a single 10G speed, rather than allowing user/driver configurable settings. AFAIK multi-speed SFP+ transceivers are uncommon.